# How to change from own Internal/Extrernal DNS to use an outsourced service like DNS Made Easy?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

Our current setup is a co-located linux box with an openvz kernel with a handful virtual containers for www, mail etc. and one container run Bind9 with a split views configuration serving External and Internal DNS. The HW-Node runs a shorewall firewall and all containers uses private ip's. The box (and DNS) basically handles web and mail for a handful domains and it works well but we still think it would be a good idea to outsource the public DNS and now to my question...

Although I am fairly comfortable with the server stuff and DNS, I'm far from a pro and guess I basically need some confirmation that I am thinking in the right direction in that I basically just move the content of our external view (with zone files) to the external service and keep the internal view (or actually remove the view), update the new external DNS with thier names servers, update the info at my registrar and wait for propagation or have I missed something?

Maybe someone else here run something similar already and can share some exteriences? I found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/25809/dns-consolidation-how-to-serve-both-internal-network-and-the-internet) which at least confirms it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do pretty much what you describe.

At least some DNS providers can also act as DNS slaves (rather than masters) - so you could keep your DNS hosted locally, as well as having a usable offsite replica of the data for if your server is offline.

I presume you are doing this just to ensure DNS availability?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you got it.

I had used DNS Made Easy for external DNS services. I liked the management of DNS on Windows since we were using that for internal dns. So what I did was use the Secondary DNS Services of DNS Made Easy and pointed them to my external master.   Then for the NS records for the domain I had three DNS Made Easy Servers and our single external DNS server. That way only 1/4 of dns queries when to our real one - another choice would have to to just use the DNS Made Easy server. - they do not have a API or a way to script change that I know of. For that DNS Stuff may have an API.

Just remember you can to test, confirm , test records and the zone file ---- that before changing NS records at your registar.

Mark

Comment: Are you using DNS failover? I'm devided between choosing the Small Business or Business membership plan, the latter including DNS failover but not sure how to interpret this sentence of their presentation "you don't have to worry about installing any special software or scripts on any of your systems. We take care of all of the work for you.". Have supplied a ticket but no reply yet but does it really mean if my server fail to serve they will serve froma copy of it or what? Sounds too good to be true though and imagine I need to have another service ready somewhere to redirect to? If you know.

Comment: Well got answer from DME "Joakim,

With our Failover service, you would need to have your own backup server/site. We would just be redirecting your domain to the secondary site if your primary site is down."